# SublimeREPL Shell

Tags: sublimetext, sublimerepl

Simple question: by default it does not display current path, but only

```
bash-3.2$
```

I wonder if one can configure SublimeREPL such that it display current path (I can of course use `pwd`, but it'd be great if it is shown automatically on screen)?

Comment: Off topic: how did you get `bash` in sublimerepl? I only have `shell`, which doesn't allow running bash scripts. :(

Answer (score 0):

For configure open `Preferences | Package Settings | SublimeREPL | Settings - User` and try to override the environment variable `PS1`:

```js
{
    "default_extend_env": {
        "PS1": "\\w\\$"
    }
}
```

Requires restart Shell to apply changes.